# Call to wget from PHP's shell_exec not working

Tags: php, shell, wget, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a PHP script locally that scrapes Google with `wget` and dumps the HTML into `temp.html`.

Running this command from the terminal works fine:

```
wget -O temp.html http://www.google.ca
```

Running this command from PHP also works fine (so it's not a permissions issue):

```
shell_exec('touch temp.html');
```

But running this from PHP does not work (does not create temp.html):

```
shell_exec('wget -O temp.html http://www.google.ca');
```

Any suggestions?  Wrapping that last command in a `var_dump()` outputs null.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to add the specific error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error.  As I stated in the question, the `shell_exec` command is not creating the file `temp.html` with the contents of `http://www.google.ca` in it.  Thanks.

Comment: Is wget installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, I'm running this from my computer, where wget is installed.  And running the same command from the same folder in terminal works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man wget`, using `wget -O temp.html http://google.com` takes all documents, concatenates them and prints everything in `temp.html`, without producing any `stdout` so PHP's `shell_exec` doesn't return anything (`null`).

The content of the scraped webpage should be present in `temp.html`, but `shell_exec("wget ...")` does not return anything, as not output is produced.

As you mentioned the webpage you are trying to scrape does not work, maybe they implemented some sort of bot-protection preventing exactly what you are trying.

**Edit:** You may use `-` to print everything to `stdout` instead. So try using `shell_exec("wget -O - https://google.com");` should return the content of the requested page to your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  If the webpage had implemented some sort of bot-protection, then running `wget -O temp.html http://www.whoever.com` directly from the terminal would not work either, but it does... right?

Comment: Correct, if there was some sort of protection (i.e. showing a Browser-check page or nothing for a visitor assumed to be a bot), `wget` should not return your desired content/code/HTML (according to my experience).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to provide full path to the `wget` binary as it seems the user that runs your script does  ot have the same $PATH as you.

Answer (score -1):

How about using `file_put_contents` & `file_get_contents` instead? This should work without having to worry about `wget`.

```
 <?php
  $filename = 'temp.html';
  $address = 'http://www.google.ca';
  file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($address));
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks and that does work for Google, however I just used Google as an example.  The actual URLs I am scraping do not work with `file_get_contents` (the server blocks the requests -- same for cURL requests).